# Place points with variable density

Tags: python, algorithm, radial-gradients

Assume that you have an `NxM` matrix, with values ranging from [0,100]. What I'd like to do is place points with a density (inversely) relative to the values in that area.

For example, here's a 2D Gaussian field, inverted s.t. the centroid has a value of 0, and the perimeter is at 100:

[image: Gaussian field]

I'd like to pack the points so that they appear somewhat similar to this image:

[image: Point overlay]

Note how there is a radial spread outwards.

My attempt looks a little different :( ...

[image]

What I attempt to do is (i) generate a boolean area, of the same shape and size, and (ii) move through the rows and columns. If the value of the boolean array at some point is `True`, then pass; otherwise, add a `[row,col]` point to a list and cover the boolean array with `True` in a radius proportional to the value in the Gaussian array.

The choice of Gaussian for this example isn't important, the fundamental idea is that: given a floating point matrix, how can one place points with a density proportional to those values?

Any help very much appreciated :)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from math import exp

def gaussian(x,y,x0,y0,A=10.0,sigma_x=10.0,sigma_y=10.0):
    return A - A*exp(-((x-x0)**2/(2*sigma_x**2) + (y-y0)**2/(2*sigma_y**2)))

def generate_grid(width=100,height=100):
    grid = np.empty((width,height))
    for x in range(0,width):
        for y in range(0,height):
            grid[x][y] = gaussian(x,y,width/2,height/2,A=100.0)
    return grid

def cover_array(a,row,col,radius):
    nRows = np.shape(grid)[0]
    nCols = np.shape(grid)[1]
    mid = round(radius / 2)
    half_radius = int(round(radius))
    for x in range(-half_radius,half_radius):
        for y in range(-half_radius,half_radius):
            if row+x >= 0 and x+row < nRows and col+y >= 0 and y+col < nCols:
                if (x-mid)**2 + (y-mid)**2 <= radius**2:
                    a[row+x][col+y] = True


def pack_points(grid):
    points = []
    nRows = np.shape(grid)[0]
    nCols = np.shape(grid)[1]
    maxDist = 50.0
    minDist = 0.0
    maxEdge = 10.0
    minEdge = 5.0
    grid_min = 0.0
    grid_max = 100.0

    row = 0
    col = 0

    arrayCovered = np.zeros((nRows,nCols))

    while True:
        if row >= nRows:
            return np.array(points)

        if arrayCovered[row][col] == False:
            radius = maxEdge * ((grid[row][col] - grid_min) / (grid_max - grid_min))
            cover_array(arrayCovered,row,col,radius)
            points.append([row,col])

        col += 1
        if col >= nCols:
            row += 1
            col = 0

grid = generate_grid()
plt.imshow(grid)
plt.show()

points = pack_points(grid)

plt.scatter(points[:,0],points[:,1])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Do the points need to be "aligned" in some way, or is it okay if they are placed kinda randomly but with adequate densities?

Comment: @jdehesa Just the density is important. Thanks!

Comment: First, add up the densities of all points in any order, computing for the i-th point the corresponding interval (sumOfDensitiesUpToPoint[i-1], sumOfDensitiesUpToPoint[i]).  Now choose a random number between 0 and the overall sum, and find out which interval it hits -- that tells you the location for this sample.  Repeat as necessary.  (You may want to record points that have already been sampled and repeat them).  You can speed up finding the interval with a binary search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a cheap and simple method, although it requires hand-setting an `amount` parameter:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def gaussian(x,y,x0,y0,A=10.0,sigma_x=10.0,sigma_y=10.0):
    return A - A*np.exp(-((x-x0)**2/(2*sigma_x**2) + (y-y0)**2/(2*sigma_y**2)))

def distribute_points(data, amount=1):
    p = amount * (1 / data)
    r = np.random.random(p.shape)
    return np.where(p > r)

ii, jj = np.mgrid[-10:10:.1, -10:10:.1]
data = gaussian(ii, jj, 0, 0)
px, py = distribute_points(data, amount=.03)

plt.imshow(data)
plt.scatter(px, py, marker='.', c='#ff000080')
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
plt.xlim([0, len(ii)])
plt.ylim([0, len(jj)])
```

Result:

[image: Points]